# Как настроить django рядом с gitlab?

Tags: django, nginx, ssl, gitlab

На сервере установлен gitlab висит он на субдомене git.domain.com, мне нужно что бы сайт висел на domain.com, при попытке перейти по этому домену браузер ругается на отсутствие ssl, я пробовал нагуглить у меня получился вот такой конфиг

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/web/project/uwsgi_nginx.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8001;

    listen 444 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:444 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/gitlab/ssl/domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/gitlab/ssl/domain.com.key; 

    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
    alias /home/web/project/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
    alias /home/web/project/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /home/web/project/deployment/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Но результат тот же, браузер ругается на отсутствие ssl.
Я пробовал выключить letsencrypt `letsencrypt['enable'] = false`  в настройках гитлаб `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
после чего я выполнил команду `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` но gitlab все равно использует ssl.

Я не понимаю как настроить nginx что бы заработал мой сайт

Comment: У вас гитлаб вообще работает? Потому что, как я помню, гитлаб без настроенного ssl просто не позволит работать. И тогда задача к чему сводится? что значит "сайт висел на domain.com" - сайт - это не гитлаб?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ алгоритм решения Вашей задачи. Пишу по памяти - о настройке gitlab и nginx, если что то непонятно - спрашивайте в комментариях.

1. Проверить, что гитлаб нормально работает на домене  git.domain.com по https и что его порты, по которым он "торчит наружу" какие нибудь нестандартные, типа 1080 и 1443. Это можно поправить в конфигах гиталаба. Как прикрытить к гитлабу letsencrypt - сертификат - так это каждый школьник знает.
2. Проверить, что "сайт" (как я понимаю, под "сайтом" понимается ) какой то сайт "на django" тоже нормально работает по протоколу https и тоже на нестандартном порту.
3. Все, теперь осталось настроить nginx так, чтобы он принимал запросы на стандартных портах и работал "регулировщиком", направляя запрос то на "сайт", то на на gitlab.

Как я понимаю, чтобы выполнить 3-й пункт - надо настраивать nginx примерно по такой инструкции: [настройка nginx с самого начала](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru)

То есть, что я делаю: я убираю всю сложность из конфига nginx, перенося его роль тупо на "разруливателя виртуальных хостов"

Comment: Я тут понял что nginx который обслуживает gitlab уже использует порт 80, следовательно nginx который обслуживает мой сайт не запускается если в конфиге тоже стоит порт 80. Подскажете как быть ?

Comment: У гитлаба есть файл настроек, в котором указывается, на какие порты ему "повеситься". Как это настраивать - зависит от способа установки гитлаба. У вас задача осложняется тем, что нужно "отделить" установку гитлаба и Вашего сайта. Можно попробовать устарновку гитлаба в контейнер или в виртуальную машину - это уменьшило бы количество зависимостей.

Comment: Если я установлю gitlab в контейнере то он же все равно будет занимать 80 порт или это уже будет не важно и могу ли я в таком случае установить сайт с nginx-ом в контейнер вместо гитлаба ?

Comment: при запуске контейнера у Вас есть возможность настраивать маппинг портов - параметр -p в команде docker run